# How to generate random true/false result in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Iam new to anylogic. I want to generate random true false results to control parameter in Select Output.

I used this if else conditions in my source

```
if(randomTrue(0.25)){
    if(randomTrue(0.5)){
        agent.isOnlineRezerve = true;
    }else { 
        agent.isOnlineRezerve = false;
    }
}else{
    agent.isOnlineRezerve = false;
}
```

My condition of source output is

```
agent.isOnlineRezerve
```

Every time I run it it gives me 128 out of 1000 true and the rest false

I want to get a number other than 128 each time, but I couldn't do it. I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyLogic is using a fixed seed to the random number generator, so that independent runs produce equivalent results. To switch to a random seed:

> To set up random number generator seed
>
> 1. In the Projects view, select the experiment you are currently working with.
> 2. Go to the Randomness section of the Properties view.
> 3. In the Random number generation group of buttons:
>
> - To set random seed, choose the Random seed (unique experiments) option.
> - To set fixed seed, choose the Fixed seed (reproducible experiments) option > and enter the seed value in the Seed value edit box.

From https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/random-number-generator.html

Comment: I was trying to find the difference between two projects for 2 hours. Thank you so much you saved me.

Comment: Glad to help! In general, this is true of pseudo-random number generators: they need a unique seed; otherwise they produce the same sequence over independent runs.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to this question, is to use the second argument of that function in order to use your own random number generator with a seed of your choice:

```
randomTrue(0.5,new Random())
```

And if you want to use your own seed for an individual calculation

```
randomTrue(0.5,new Random(33))
```